# Is it possible to represent functional linear operators like the differential operator as a “continuous matrix”?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Consider a function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, and consider it as a vector in the space of functions from $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

Just as how a linear operator on a finite $n$-dimensional vector space $\mathbb R^n$ can be represented by a $n$-$n$ matrix, i.e. an element of $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, we *could* consider a linear operator on $\mathbb R^\mathbb R$ to be represented by an $R$ by $R$ function, i.e. an element of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R\times \mathbb R}=\mathbb R^{\mathbb R^2}$.

So we could consider a (differentiable) function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, and a “continuous matrix” $D:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$.

**The analogous operation to “matrix multiplication” would be:**

$$Df(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty D(x,y)f(y)dy$$

Linear operators of this form are called “**linear integral operator**s”. **It seems to me that no such $D(x,y)$ exists that would make $Df(x)$ be the derivative of $f(x)$.** But perhaps something like a generalized function $D(x,y)$, analogous to the dirac-delta function?

- Am I right that no $D(x,y)$ exists that represents the derivative operator (i.e. the derivative cannot be represented as a linear integral operator)? What are the implications of this? I have almost no knowledge of functional analysis, and I’m trying to get a better idea.
- How far can we go with representing linear operators as “infinite dimensional matrices” like this? How powerful is this approach? It seems to me that it is not very powerful, and I’m trying to understand what functional analysists do to overcome this.
- Intuitions about finite dimensional vector spaces/linear algebra, don’t always transfer to infinite-dimensional vector spaces/functional analysis. Is the fact that not all linear operators are linear integral operators the “reason” for this? I.e. do properties of finite dimensional linear operators transfer to linear integral operators?

Comment: The space of functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is a bad space. You need some regularity conditions on this space, ie letting your functions be continuous or continuously differentiable. Then choose a natural topology compatible with the condition. An example of such a space is [Schwartz-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space). Differentiation is continuous on Schwartz space. But it is not the form $f\mapsto (x\mapsto \int D(x,y) f(y)dy)$. The condition that an operator is of that form is rather restrictive, in general you should expect if $D$ is continuous that he operator is compact.

Comment: Aren't these called [integral transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform) or [linear integral operators](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Integral_operator)?

Comment: @Rahul, yes it seems they are.